# Do dragonmark spell-like abilities add to Sorcerer's spells known?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, feats, sorcerer, eberron

I am playing in a Eberron *Pathfinder* campaign.

Do the spells from this [Least True Dragonmark](https://sites.google.com/site/eberronpathfinder/conversion-info/feats/dragonmark-feats#least_true_dragonmark) feat get added to a sorcerer spell's known list if you get the feat?

Comment: Could you replace 'these' with a reference to what the spells are, for the sake of posterity if the site goes down? (I would, but I don't know much about the system in question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Least True Dragonmark, Lesser True Dragonmark, and Greater True Dragonmark feats, as well as the Siberys mark ability of the heir of Siberys, do not affect, and are not affected by, sorcerer spellcasting. Those spell-like abilities are completely independent. This was equally-true of their original 3.5e counterparts.

However, in *Dragon* magazine vol. 351 (for 3.5e, back when Paizo published *Dragon* for Wizards of the Coast), there is another feat called Dragonmarked Sorcerer, that you can take **instead of** the usual Dragonmark feats. If you do, you learn the Dragonmark’s spells as sorcerer spells once you reach the appropriate sorcerer level, instead of learning them as spell-like abilities by taking more feats. This will do what you’re looking for, and is (unsurprisingly, given the name) mostly a better answer for a Dragonmarked sorcerer than the separate Dragonmark feats are. Note that the 3.5e Dragonmark feats did not give you choices for which spells you get as spell-like abilities, so Dragonmarked Sorcerer doesn’t either—presumably you would simply get the same choices as a sorcerer, but you’ll have to work that out with your GM. As GM, I might rule that the other options that you don’t choose get added to your sorcerer spell list, if they aren’t already, so you could choose them as regular sorcerer spells with your regular spells known.

---

Personally, if it were me, I’d probably implement Dragonmarked Sorcerer in Pathfinder instead as a bloodline, not as a feat, but that’s more work. Would have been nice if the people who put together this Pathfinder Eberron site had done that work, but as *Dragon* material, Dragonmarked Sorcerer is pretty obscure, so they probably just didn’t realize it existed. If they’re taking suggestions, you might mention it to them.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see, no.

They are a spell-like ability completely seperate from the Sorcerer's Spells class feature.
You do count as knowing them for feat prerequisites and such, however.